# How to properly close a Node.js TCP server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, tcp, server

I couldn't find a clear answer on Google or SO.

I know a `net.Server` instance has a `close` method that doesn't allow any more clients in. But it doesn't disconnect clients already connected. How can I achieve that?

I know how this can be done with Http, I guess I'm asking if it's the same with Tcp or if it's different.

With Http, I'd do something like this:

```
var http = require("http");

var clients = [];

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end("You sent a request.");
});

server.on("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.write("You connected.");
    clients.push(socket);
});

// .. later when I want to close
server.close();
clients.forEach(function(client) {
    client.destroy();
});
```

Is it the same for Tcp? Or should I do anything differently?

Comment: yes, the same. Keep list of connected clients and close all active before doing `server.close()` if you need hard shutdown ( but if it's really "hard" just doing `process.exit()` might be better)

Comment: Don't forget to remove sockets when they disconnect too (e.g. the socket's `close` event), otherwise you will end up with an ever-increasing socket array containing potentially dead sockets.

Answer (score 13):

Since no answer was provided, here is an example of how to open and (hard) close a server in node.js:

Create the server:

```
var net = require('net');

var clients = [];
var server = net.createServer();

server.on('connection', function (socket) {
    clients.push(socket);
    console.log('client connect, count: ', clients.length);

    socket.on('close', function () {
        clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
    });
});

server.listen(8194);
```

Close the server:

```
// destroy all clients (this will emit the 'close' event above)
for (var i in clients) {
    clients[i].destroy();
}
server.close(function () {
    console.log('server closed.');
    server.unref();
});
```

**Update:** Since using the above code, I've ran into an issue that `close` will leave the port open (TIME_WAIT in Windows). Since I'm intentionally closing the connection, I'm using [unref](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_unref) as it appears to fully close the tcp server, though I'm not 100% if this is the correct way of closing the connection.

Comment: TIME_WAIT is the kernel, not the process, keeping the socket alive because of TCP protocol rules.
Node.js sets the SO_REUSEADDR flag when creating a new net.Server, so the fact that the old kernel connection record is still there doesn't impact further use.

Answer (score 0):

I am using NodeJS `v16.13.2` ... When the process containing the server code exits, all clients connection are closed/destroyed by default.

I came here to find out how I could listen for a `server.("exit", myTaskCallback)`, since I wanted to delete some files while exiting the server. But the answer I have found is that such event does not exists. I had to listen to `process.on('exit', myTaskCallback)` to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

1. sock.end(); //to correctly send the end of the connection in both sides
2. sock.on("close", fn) //add event listeners to destory all related sockets and clients
3. sock.on("close", () => { sock.destroy() }) //to destroy your side socket wrapper

Example:

```
  const closeConn = async (sock, cb) => {
    sock.ev.on("close", async ()=>{
      await sock?.destroy();
      if (typeof cb === "function") cb();
    });
    await sock?.end();
  }

  closeConn(sock, openSock);
```

[You can check more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191587/how-to-disconnect-from-tcp-socket-in-nodejs)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31936246)